# Laravel: Controller does not exist

Tags: laravel-4, controller, autoload

I added new controller in /app/controllers/admin/ folder and added the route in /app/routes.php file as well. Then i run the following command to autoload them

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

I got the following error

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
```

I followed instruction given at https://askubuntu.com/questions/460837/mcrypt-extension-is-missing-in-14-04-server-for-mysql and able to resolve the mcrypt issue.

After that i run the `php artisan dump-autoload` command but still getting following error

```
{"error":{"type":"ReflectionException","message":"Class CoursesController does not exist","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Container\/Container.php","line":504}}
```

Here is code of my **routes.php** file

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'adminauth', 'except' => array('/admin/login', '/admin/logout')), function() {
    Route::resource('/admin/courses', 'CoursesController');
    Route::resource('/admin/teachers', 'TeachersController');    
    Route::resource('/admin/subjects', 'SubjectsController');
});
```

Here is code of **CoursesController.php** file

```
<?php

class CoursesController extends BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {
        $courses = Course::where('is_deleted', 0)->get();
        return View::make('admin.courses.index', compact('courses'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('admin.courses.create');
    }

   public function store()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Course::$rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $messages = $validator->messages();
            $response = '';
            foreach ($messages->all(':message') as $message) {
                $response = $message;
            }
            return Response::json(array('message'=>$response, 'status'=>'failure'));
        } else {
            Course::create($data);
            return Response::json(array('message'=>'Course created successfully','status'=>'success'));
        }
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $course = Course::find($id);
        return View::make('admin.courses.edit', compact('course'));
    }

    public function update($id)
    {
        $course = Course::findOrFail($id);
        $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Course::editRules($id));

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $messages = $validator->messages();
            $response = '';
            foreach ($messages->all(':message') as $message) {
                $response = $message;
            }
            return Response::json(array('message'=>$response, 'status'=>'failure'));
        } else {
            $course->update($data);
            return Response::json(array('message'=>'Course updated successfully','status'=>'success'));
        }
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Course::findOrFail($id)->update(array('is_deleted' => '1'));
        return Response::json(array('message'=>'Course deleted successfully','status'=>'success'));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code located in CoursesController.php

Comment: I have added the code. This issue belongs to our staging server but it is working fine at my local system

Comment: make sure Yoy are PASSING the correct arguments to the Controller function

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you add autoload classmap to composer.json file?
Open your composer.json file and add

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/controllers/admin",
        ]
    }
```

if you add folders inside controllers, you need to add it to composer.json file. Then run

```
composer dumpautoload
```

**OR ALTERNATIVE**

go to app/start/global.php and add

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path().'/controllers/admin',
));
```

Comment: The problem is that other controllers of admin folders are working but only this controller is not working

Comment: try  this: extends \BaseController

Comment: It has worked by adding admin folder in global.php but my question is why it is working for other newly added controllers ?

Comment: "composer dumpautload" should have worked or you needed "composer update". Sometimes I clear out app/storage/views folder and it works.

Comment: `composer dumpautoload` was my problem

Comment: this is worked! thanks... btw @SushantAryal do you have explanation why we need to run `composer dumpautoload` because i recheck my code so many times but not wrong...

Comment: @anunixercoder This solution is for Laravel 4. Since version 4 didn't use psr autoload, in order to reflect the changes done in composer.json you have to run `composer dumpautoload`. As you can see above we have added the admin directory to the controllers. Or you can use the alternative solution if you don't want to run `composer dumpautoload`. If you are using any version above 5 you can add any number of directory inside controllers as long as you properly namespace it.

Answer (score 13):

**2021 answer (Laravel 8.5)**

In your controller;

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request){
        return "login";
    }
}
```

In your routes;

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
```

Doc = https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files

Comment: worked, maybe accepted answere should be updated

Answer (score 9):

In my case, in the top of my controller code i add this line :

> namespace App\Http\Controllers\CustomFolder\ControllerClassName;

and my problem is solved

Comment: This is the cause! Happens usually after you move your controller class into a directory and forget to change the namespace. Thank You! :)

Answer (score 8):

We can create controller via command line.

`php artisan make:controller nameController --plain`.

Before Laravel 5, make namespace is not available. Instead, this works

`php artisan controller:make nameController`

Execute your command inside your project directory and then create your function.

Comment: "need" is a strong word. The make artisan commands are nothing but convenience methods, you don't need to use them

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget to do:

`php artisan route:clear`

In my case this was the solution when I got this error after making a route code change.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I had to change the route file from this:

```
Route::get('/','SessionController@accessSessionData');
```

to this:

```
Route::get('/','App\Http\Controllers\SessionController@accessSessionData');
```

then clearing the cache with this:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

made things work.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late but in my experience adding this to the RouteServiceProvider.php solves the problem

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

Comment: This is a handy solution to keep optimizing the route file otherwise requires a long list of the `use` statements for each controller class. So, use the $namespace property and define a route path as like:
`Route::get('/users', 'Api\User\UserController@index');`

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem has already been fixed. But this is what did.

Structure

```
Http
  .Auth
  .CustomControllerFolder
    -> CustomController.php
```

to get this working
in your route file make sure you use the correct name space
for eg:

```
  Route::group(['namespace'=>'CustomControllerFolder','prefix'=>'prefix'],
      function() {

   //define your route here
}
```

Also dont forget to use `namespace App\Http\Controllers\CustomControllerFolder` in your controller.

That should fix the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue because I renamed a file from `EmployeeRequestContoller` to `EmployeeRequestsContoller`, but when I renamed it I missed the `.php` extension!

When I reran `php artisan make:controller EmployeeRequestsContoller` just to be sure I wasn't going crazy and the file showed up I could clearly see the mistake:

```
/EmployeeRequestsContoller
/EmployeeRequestsContoller.php
```

Make sure you have the extension if you've renamed!

Answer (score 2):

I use Laravel 9 this is the way we should use controllers

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
 
Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we are missing `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` on top of our controller code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have several backup files of admin and home controllers renamed with different dates and we ran a composer update on top of it and it gave us an error

after I removed the other older controller files and re-ran the composer update fixed my issue.

```
 - Clue - composer update command gave us a warning.
```

Generating optimized autoload files

```
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Controllers\HomeController" was found in both "app/core/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController(25-OCT).php" and "app/core/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php", the first will be used.

Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Controllers\AdminController" was found in both "app/core/app/Http/Controllers/AdminController(25-OCT).php" and "app/core/app/Http/Controllers/AdminController.php", the first will be used.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use full namespace inside `web.php`

```
Route::resource('myusers','App\Http\Controllers\MyUserController');
```

Answer (score 0):

this format solves it for recent versions

```
   Route::post('decline', [UserController::class, 'decline'])->name('user.decline');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue and I figure out that I did a silly mistake in naming so to make sure you don't have any naming problems check the names in:

1- `web.php` or `api.php`

2- file name`YourController.php`:

3- name of the class `class YourController extends` controller{}`

api.php:

```
use DommyController;
Route::get('dommy-route', DommyController::class, 'dommyFunction']);
```

DommyController.php:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class DommyController extends Controller
{
    public function index
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

in `api.php` or `web.php` if you're using `'namespace'` you should be should to use correct path of the class

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'v1',
    'namespace' => 'Api\V1'
], function() {
   use DommyController;
   Route::get('dommy-route', DommyController::class, 'dommyFunction']);
});
```